# Copy- paste on Virtual machine from esx console.

Tags: vmware-esx

I think this is very basic question but I could not find the answer anywhere, probably you guys can help.

I use ESX 3.5 and it has 30 VM instances. These VMs are still not on the network. I want to copy and paste same commands in 'rc.local' of all these VMs.  I am accessing these VMs by login in to ESX and getting console of each VM. Is there any way I can copy these commands and paste them in 'rc.local' of each VM through this console. Because through this console you can not release mouse so I am unable to paste the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it, it's not supported on ESX/ESXi for security reasons - you can do it on Workstation/Fusion though.

Comment: That's what I thought:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Putty to SSH into the VMs and then cut/paste or if the files are identical opn each machine, use SCP to copy the rc.local files to each machine

Comment: Phil I can't do what you suggested because VMs are not on network.